# How to nest http calls in angular

Tags: http, rxjs, nested, angular-httpclient

Hi I need to nest 3 calls in Angular9. where :

1. All call's are inter-dependent
2. All calls can give error

a.How can i write the code in a better way?

b.Can i use RXJS?

c.How to nest along with error block in RXJS?

example:

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1').subscribe(character => {
      this.http.get('/api/people/character ').subscribe(homeworld => {
            this.http.get('/api/people/character/homeworld  ').subscribe(finalResponse=> {
                 console.log(finalResponse);
            },
             error =>{
                  console.log(error);
            });
      },
      error =>{
           console.log(error);
      });
},
error =>{
   console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) may help you understand the main mechanics of rxjs with http calls

Answer (score 2):

You will need a `higher-order mapping operator` to be able to make only once subscription, for example, a `switchMap`.

```js
const getPeople = id => this.http.get(`/api/people/${id}`);
const getCharacter = character => this.http.get(`/api/people/${character}`);
const getCharacterAgain = character => this.http.get(`/api/people/character/${character}`);

getPeople(1).pipe(
  switchMap(getCharacter),
  switchMap(getCharacterAgain),
).subscribe(...);
```